# Invert text color of TextView depending on background color?

Tags: android, colors

is there a way to invert the color of my text view depending on my background colors?

I am thinking of setting a black to white gradient background and have my TextView scrolled through it. I noticed that I could not have a single text color for my TextView.

For example, If I set the text color to black, it will not be shown when over black background, same goes for white text on white background.

Is there a property or method I can use to quickly show the text in the opposite color of my background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that simple but yes, technically you can do this.

First you'll need to set up an `onScrollListener` on your scrollable view (eg. `ListView`, `GridView`, `ScrollView`

in the `onScrollListener()`, you will need to implement the `onScroll()` method.

> onScroll (AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)

At this point you know that the use is scrolling. You can then check where on the screen your `TextView` `mTextView` is.

> int distanceFromTop = mTextView.getTop();

and change you text color depending on the distance from the top.